# jQuery onchange: validate value from textbox in repeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, textbox, repeater

i have a textbox inside a repeater. i want to validate the value that will be entered in the textbox. i use the onchange event (tried the oninput also) in my textbox but its not working. Please help me figure out whats wrong with my code cause im new to web developing (im new to jquery, asp.net, vb.net and html). also, if you could give some advise, i wish to create a single function that will do the validation and will apply it to 4 different textboxes. i know that my codes are too lame. thank you in advance.

Here's my script

```
$("#Text1").on('change input', function () {
    var qtyReqd = $(this).val();
    var qtyAvail = $("#anymfg-qtyavail").val();
    if (qtyReqd > qtyAvail) {
        alert("The required quantity cannot be more than the available quantity");
        qtyReqd = $(this).val(qtyAvail);
    }
});

$("#Text2").change(function () {
    var qtyReqd = $(this).val();
    var qtyAvail = $("#instock-qtyavail").val();
    if (qtyReqd > qtyAvail) {
        alert("The required quantity cannot be more than the available quantity");
        qtyReqd = $(this).val(qtyAvail);
    }
});

$("#Text3").change(function () {
    var qtyReqd = $(this).val();
    var qtyAvail = $("#outofstock-qtyavail").val();
    if (qtyReqd > qtyAvail) {
        alert("The required quantity cannot be more than the available quantity");
        qtyReqd = $(this).val(qtyAvail);
    }
});

$("#Text4").change(function () {
    var qtyReqd = $(this).val();
    var qtyAvail = $("#outofstockalt-qtyavail").val();
    if (qtyReqd > qtyAvail) {
        alert("The required quantity cannot be more than the available quantity");
        qtyReqd = $(this).val(qtyAvail);
    }
});
```

HTML code

```
<div id="anymfg">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptAnyMfg" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div id="anymfgrow">
                    <div class="manufacturer">
                        <%# CType(Container.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Item("Mfg").ToString%></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="anymfg-qtyavail" class="qty-avail">
                        <%# CType(Container.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Item("Qty").ToString%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="qty-required">
                        <input id="Text1" type="text" onkeypress="return validate(event);" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
    <div id="in-stock">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptInStock" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="in-stock">
                    <div class="manufacturer">
                        <%# CType(Container.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Item("Mfg").ToString%>
                    </div>
                    <div id="instock-qtyavail" class="qty-avail">
                        <%# CType(Container.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Item("Qty").ToString%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="qty-required">
                        <input id="Text2" type="text" onkeypress="return validate(event);"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
    <div id="out-of-stock">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptOutOfStock" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptOutOfStock_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div ID="outofstock_row" class="out-of-stock" runat="server">
                    <div class="manufacturer">
                        <%# CType(Container.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Item("Mfg").ToString%>
                    </div>
                    <div id="outofstock-qtyavail" class="qty-avail">
                        <%# CType(Container.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Item("Qty").ToString%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="qty-required">
                        <input id="Text3" type="text" onkeypress="return validate(event);"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <div class="out-of-stock-alt">
                    <div class="manufacturer">
                        <%# CType(Container.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Item("Mfg").ToString%>
                    </div>
                    <div id="outofstockalt-qtyavail" class="qty-avail">
                        <%# CType(Container.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Item("Qty").ToString%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="qty-required">
                        <input id="Text4" type="text" onkeypress="return validate(event);"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </AlternatingItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
```

my new script code: (please disregard the first one above i did not remove it since it was my first post). i call this function on every onchange event but its kinda working only on the first row of the repeater. why is that?

```
function ValidateQty() {
    var qtyreqd = document.getElementById("Text1").value;
    var qtyavail1 = document.getElementById("anymfg-qtyavail");
    var qtyavail = qtyavail1.childNodes[0].nodeValue.trim();
    if (qtyreqd > qtyavail) {
        alert("The required quantity cannot be more than the available quantity");
        $("#Text1").val(qtyavail);
    //alert(qtyavail);
    }
}
```

Comment: anyone? please help me.. i searched and googled but i cant seem to find the right way for my project.. i want to use the function to all textbox in the repeater.. my function kind of able to see only the first row.. please help.. thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `validateElement` `function` and call that from your events, this is just an example:

```
function validateElement(id, value) {
    switch (id) {
        case "name": return ((!!value) ? ("") : ("Required"));
        case "description": return ((!!value) ? ("") : ("Required"));
        case "price": {
                if (!value) {
                    return "Required";
                } else if (isNaN(value)) {
                    return "Not a number";
                } else {
                    return "";
                }
        }
        case "email": return ((!!value) ? ("") : ("Required"));
        default: return "";
    }
}
```

Then you can implement a `blur` event, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#myForm").on("blur", "#name, #description, #price, #email", function() {
        alert(validateElement("Response is " + $(this).attr("id"), $(this).val()));
    });
});
```

Now, about your problem, I am not sure `Text1`, `Text2`, `Text3` and `Text4` already exists when you attach events to them. However, I am not sure I exactly get what you mean by "its not working". That's too broad.

Comment: im not sure also if they're already created, but i think they are... i'll check on that. with regards to your question, i want to replace the value inputted by the user with the qty-avail value. thats not working, thats why i know my jquery is not working. thanks for the advise. i will try that to simplify my validate function.

Comment: Yes, but your Javascript might be running before your markup generates the relevant part of the HTML. In this case the elements do not exist (yet) when you try to define jQuery events for them. In my answer I have shown how can you put an event declaration inside the page load event, also, to make sure that the event will be applicable to currently existent elements as well as elements which will be generated in the future.

Comment: hi Lajos, my script is now working but i havent integrated yet your suggestion for one function. i just want to make my function work first but my problem now is that it is working in the first row only, why do you think is that since i've put it as an onchange event to the input box (inside the repeater). thanks.

Comment: Please look at the generated html in your browser. You can do that by right-cicking anywhere and choosing inspect element if you are using google chrome. Also, if we are already here, you have shared your markup, but I need to see the generated HTML to give you a more precise answer to your question in the comment. I guess that only your first row has that id in your generated html

Comment: in the generated HTML all the textboxes has the same ID. Im expecting that it will generate a unique id for each textbox with prefix as Text2. How do i make it unique and be able to find it? i just put the textbox in the repeater (drag a input to the repeater in html) or should it be like a dynamically created?

Comment: ive changed the html input to asp textbox and add onchange attributes in behind code. using (this) in the function call i was able to get the value of the current textbox that is being changed. i still have problem cause i need to get the qty-avail value of that row with changed text in textbox. its really one step at a time for me. :)

Comment: Based on the textbox you can reach the inner text of the element having qty-avail class in the same row: call the foobar.parent().parent().find(".qty-avail").text() method, where foobar is the result of jQuery search on the textbox.

Comment: thanks @lajos, finally got it working. thanks for guiding me. im wondering what the onblur for? i didnt put that in my codes.

Answer (score 0):

here's the jquery function i used for onchange event on every textbox that i have in the repeater. i used the (this) function to identify the current row being changed then used the .parent().siblings to trackdown the element that i want to get the value from. i've learned that you cannot compare a number (in string) so i need to convert the value i get to integer. i've learned alot of things in jquery for this problem.. hope this will help others too.. :)

```
function ValidateQty(txtBox) {
    var qtyreqd = parseInt(txtBox.value);
    var qtyavail = parseInt($(txtBox).parent().siblings(".qty-avail").text().trim());
    if (qtyreqd > qtyavail) {
        alert("The required quantity cannot be more than the available quantity");
        txtBox.value = qtyavail;
        txtBox.focus();
    }
}
```

html:

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" onkeypress="return validate(event);" onchange="ValidateQty(this);" />
```